# SAFE CLI: HwDevice exception: Unexpected message

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

when I try to use my Trezor with the SAFE CLI I get an error: HwDevice exception: Unexpected message. I'm able to load the trezor into the CLI fine, i can select the address/derivation path no issue, but sending gives me this error.

any thoughts?